# css min-width does not work properly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position a div centered in another div with this code:

```html
<div style="width:100%; height: 300px; background:red;">
  <div style="margin:auto; min-width:50%; height:100%; background:green;">Text</div>
</div>
```

It results in a big green div that's width is 100%. I expect it to be 50% though. Can somebody tell me why css wont give it 50% width and center it?

Comment: Maybe the parent div is overriding the child's width style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer**

```html
<div style="width:100%; height: 300px; background:red; text-align: center">
      <div style="min-width:50%; display: inline-block; height:100%; background:green;">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but I want it to have a min-width, since the content can be wider than 50%

Comment: OK. Then set it to `display:inline-block` and `width:auto` along with `min-width: 50%`.  This will make it such that the DIV is scales with its content, but gets no smaller than 50%.

Comment: just tried it. it doesnt work. the div is not centered. like margin:auto; wouldnt work anymore.

Comment: Almost there:  Because the display mode is now inline-block, you need to set `text-align:center` on the parent DIV.  I updated the answer with working markup.

Comment: And to stop the green DIV's content from being centered, add `text-align:left` to the green DIV.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the term **minimum** width...it's a minimum. The default width of a block level element is 100% so it's already over 50% and thus expands to full width.

You need to change the display property to `inline-block` and then use `text-align:center` on the parent to center the child.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well explained answer.

Answer (score 0):

The parent div where you set width to 100% dictates that the content of the div should consume 100% of the width.  The inner div says make sure that this div has a minimum width of 50%. If you would like to center and fix the width to 50% try something like

```
 <div style="margin:auto; width:50%; height:100%; background:green; 
      margin-left: auto ;margin-right: auto;">Text</div>
```

http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/center-div-block.shtml

Comment: but in this inner div there are other elements such as <span> and <ul> that wont be affected by text-align:center

Comment: if you explicitly set both margins you can center the content of the div.